# undefined reference to `dlsym'

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile QT for the raspberry PI 3 under Debian Stretch but when I use `make -j4` to compile QT, it gives the following error:

```
$ make -j4>log
/home/charlie/Rpi/qt5/qtbase/lib/libQt5EglSupport.a(qeglplatformcontext.o): In function `QEGLPlatformContext::getProcAddress(char const*)':
qeglplatformcontext.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [../../../../plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so] Error 1
make[4]: *** [sub-minimalegl-make_first] Error 2
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/charlie/Rpi/qt5/qtbase/lib/libQt5EglSupport.a(qeglplatformcontext.o): In function `QEGLPlatformContext::getProcAddress(char const*)':
qeglplatformcontext.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[6]: *** [../../../../lib/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5.8.1] Error 1
make[5]: *** [sub-eglfsdeviceintegration-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[4]: *** [sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I have read a lot of similar posts containing the same dlsym error and I have tried the solutions given in them, but no luck so far. I have proceeded as it is shown in [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide) and until now I still have doubts about the symlinks in lib directory.

When I run `sudo file * | grep broken`, 2 symlinks are reported to be broken, even after running the script that supposedly fixes the symlinks (as sudo).

```
./fixQualifiedLibraryPaths /mnt/raspberry-rootfs/ ~/Rpi/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

The symlinks that appear to be broken are listed below:

```
libblas.so.3gf:                     broken symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf
liblapack.so.3gf:                   broken symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/liblapack.so.3gf
```

The ./configure is executed as follows:

```
./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/Rpi/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/raspberry-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi
```

Do you guys can point me out what I am doing wroing?

PD: I also installed the libncurses5 and lib32z1 and I obtained qt by git cloning.

Comment: What version of Qt have you cloned?

Comment: I cloned the GIT repository of QT so I supposed it should be 5.8. I also tried with 5.7.1 and didn't work.

Comment: I followed the following [tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) and I had no problems.

Comment: I used the python script from your tutorial and I changed linux-rasp-pi-g++ for linux-rasp-pi2-g++ (I have Raspberry PI 3) and again ran configure and make. Still no luck :(. The thing is, I'd like to use QT-Creator in order to program applications for the raspberry pi, which I can compile using my computer and test them on the Raspberry.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, proceeding as you did but using the gcc-5.4.1-linaro-gnueabihf toolchain. Unfortunately I did not find the root cause, but a workaround is calling configure like

```
LIBS=-ldl ./configure ...
```

Answer (score 2):

with raspbian stretch egl libs has different names

/opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so -> /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so

/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so -> /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so

so, I eddited this file in Qt sources:

./qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++/qmake.conf
and changed

-lEGL -lGLESv2

to

-lbrcmEGL -lbrcmGLESv2

Answer (score 2):

the symlinks was broken when mount to host,

```
$ cd /mnt/raspberry-rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
$ sudo rm libdl.so 
$ sudo ln -s ../../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 libdl.so
```

Comment: Please add more context to explain the three commands you offered as the solution. For guidance, review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, tried to follow Miguel Angel Pons solution, but then realized that missed to update my raspberry with:

`sudo rpi-update`

Solution is taken from https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step. It is refferencing to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62216 and should fix the libraries exactly which compiler complains to.

After that I repeated 8 and 9 steps, cleaned up the source tree, reconfigured and finally successfully built qt for raspberry.